# Set stack navigator initialRouteName based on tab

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I have a the following Tab Navigator

```
export const MainNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" options={{ title: "Home" }} component={MainStackScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Favorite" options={{ title: "Favorite" }} component={MainStackScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Where the (simplified) `MainStackScreen` looks like this:

```
export const MainStackScreen = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerBackTitleVisible: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Favorite" component={FavoriteHomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Organisation" component={OrganisationScreen}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Leagues" component={LeaguesScreen}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Groupes" component={GroupesScreen}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Basically I would like to have a different <Stack.Navigator> `initialRouteName` depending on which tab is selected.

To give more context, the favorite tab allows user to skip some navigation steps you have on Home tab but let the user navigates threw the same screens. This is why these two tabs share the same stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
const MainStackScreen = ({route}) => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName={route.name === 'Favorite' ? 'Leagues' : 'Home'}
      screenOptions={{headerBackTitleVisible: false}}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Favorite" component={FavoriteHomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Organisation" component={OrganisationScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Leagues" component={LeaguesScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Groupes" component={GroupesScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Based on the the current route name (`Home` or `Favorite` in your case), you can set the `initialRouteName` dynamically.

In the above example if you're on the `Favorite` tab the `initialRouteName` will be `Leagues`, if not it will be `Home`.

---

In the case that you only want to skip to the `Home` stack if you're on the `Home` tab and if you're on the `Favorite` tab to skip to the `Favorite` stack, you don't need the ternary statement and you can just do this:

```
// ...
initialRouteName={route.name}
// ...
```

Comment: No need for extra params. Could just use route.name to get the name of the tab

Comment: @satya164 That is true if you want to go from the home tab to the home stack for example, but this is more flexible. You can skip to `Leagues` if you're on `Favorite` for example. But I will add your point to the answer.

Comment: I didn't mean `initialRouteName={route.name}`, but to conditionally set `initialRouteName` based on `route.name` inside the component instead of passing extra param

Comment: @satya164 Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my answer.